# Extract Text inbetween the last two | delimiters in r

Tags: r

I have the string "email|text|email|print|"

I would like the output to be the last string in between the two vertical bars.

I have tried

```
word("email|text|email|print|", -2, sep = "|")
```

no luck

I would like the output to just be "print"

Answer (score 3):

The `|` is a regex metacharacter.  We need to escape (`\\`) or place it inside square bracket (`"[|]"`) to get the literal value

```
library(stringr)
word("email|text|email|print|", -2, sep = "\\|")
#[1] "print"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is using lookbehind and lookahead:

```
x <- "email|text|email|print|"

library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\|)\\w+(?=\\|$)")
[1] "print"
```

The pattern `(?<=\\|)\\w+(?=\\|$)`can be glossed as saying: "if you see a `|`on the left and a `|` on the right followed immediately by the string end `$`, then extract the alphanumeric string in-between"

Using `word`you could add the function `fixed` to avoid having to escape `|`:

```
word("email|text|email|print|", -2, sep = fixed("|"))
```